# What type of function is $x^2+y^2+6x$?

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, graphing-functions

So, the task is to calculate the volume of body formed when the surface bounded by these functions: $y=x^2/3$ and $x^2+y^2+6x$ rotates around $x$ axis.
Everything involving the actual calculation using definite integrals, finding the limits of integral, etc. is not a problem. The real problem is, I don't understand the function: $x^2+y^2+6x$
I hope not understanding the function won't influence calculating the volume later, but anyway, when I'm given a function, for example, like this one: $y-x$, not like $y=x$ or $y-2x=0$, so without equality, what do they represent and how can I write them in form $y=f(x)$?

Comment: It's not a function, nor even a relation, unless there is an equals sign *somewhere*.  Are you sure you are  copying the problem correctly?  Something seems to be missing.

Comment: You may mean $x^2+y^2+6x=0$, in which case our curve is a circle.

Comment: You have understand $x^2+y^2+6x$ as being the function $z=x^2+y^2+6x$ which is a paraboloide.

Comment: It is a function ! It is a non-linear functional on 2-Space. The problem apparently encountered is one of notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what is meant is $x^2+y^2+6x = 0$, we can write $x^2+y^2+6x+9 = 9$.  The point of doing this is to be able to write

$$
(x+3)^2+y^2 = 9
$$

which shows that this is a circle of radius $3 = \sqrt{9}$, centered at the point $(-3, 0)$.

---

It occurs to me that one other possibility afforded by the problem is that the curve is given by

$$
y = x^2+y^2+6x
$$

That's a bit odd, but it too can be worked into the form of a circle:

$$
(x+3)^2+\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{37}{4}
$$

The end result is, of course, not quite as nice.

Comment: you seem to be assuming that the original problem involved the equation $x^2 + y^2 + 6 = 0$.  The OP explicitly said that it did *not* include an equals sign.

Comment: @mweiss But then it is not a function.

Comment: @mweiss: OP didn't quite say that, though I must admit that it sure looks as though it's implied.  I did edit my answer (just as you were leaving your comment) to say that I'm assuming the $= 0$ part.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too, but, what to do if it really is a paraboloide $z=x^2+^2+6x$ as Piquito said? It doesn't make sense to me to compare a 3D curve with a 2D curve. So I guess $=0$ is missing.

Comment: I thought that talking about volume is allowed only when the dimension is larger or equal  than 2

Comment: @A6SE: I don't think that it quite makes sense to revolve a three-dimensional object around the $x$-axis and know what is expected in terms of volume.  One could treat the volume as the envelope produced by the revolution, but that's a fairly tricky problem in general.  I suspect that is not what is intended.